How to log GPU usage using GPUWatch?
I want to log GPU usage on my app. I see there is GPUWatch option to monitor an app's GPU usage. It shows graphs but how to log this data? I need to save it.
Alternatively if there is any other ways to log GPU data, through ADB or Android Studio, please advise.

